# Where can I ask for feedback to an app that I've developed?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I have developed an universal Android app to learn words from any foreign language and would like to ask people for critics.

What else is needed to add, to clean and so on.

Can I ask this question to people from different languages stacks?

For example here
https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/
or here
https://italian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds _too broad_ for me, even in a foreign language.

Comment: What exactly? Why cons? I addressed a question to the support team.

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking for feedback on a specific piece of code you've written, you can post a question at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read [what's on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you are looking for feedback on a part of your UI, you can post a question at [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Again, be sure to read [what's on-topic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Any other kind of soliciting feedback is out of scope for the network. Asking what features people would like to see, or which bugs they've found, is not something that fits on a Q&A site.